# Do...while loop keeps looping even when condition is not met

Tags: c++, console-application, do-while

I'm writing a simple rpg console game, that I will develop overtime with graphics, etc. But right now i'm having an issue with my do...while loop. I don't use them to often but I thought it was good for this necessity. Basically, I have an opening story, then I give the user four options which they can input by pressing either "1", "2", "3", or "4". If the user types anything else, a message is supposed to display, and allow the user to type a correct input. My code is as follows:

```
int action; // Used to determine what the user wants to do.
cout << "Story goes here\n\n";
cout << "What would you like to do? (1/2/3/4)\n\n";
cout << "1. Do this\n";
cout << "2. Do that\n";
cout << "3. Do this that\n";
cout << "4. Party\n\n";

cin >> action;

do
{
  switch (action)
  {
    case 1:
      cout << "1\n";
      break;
    case 2:
      cout << "2\n";
      break;
    case 3:
      cout << "3\n";
      break;
    case 4:
      cout << "4\n";
      break;
    default:
      cout << "I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you want to do. Please tell me again using the corresponding number. (1/2/3/4)\n\n";
      cin >> action;
      break;
  }
} while ((action != 1) || (action != 2) || (action != 3) || (action != 4));
system("pause");
```

Now I've tested what happens if i type 5 or 6, it displays the default message and allows me to try again, however, if i type 1, 2, 3, or 4 it goes into the switch and keeps outputting the number that i have printing out. And it never ends. I'm using c++ with MS Visual Studio 2013 Express.

I also used the debugger and it says action is equal to 2 (or whatever number i press) and it continues to run the loop. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Your while condition logic is incorrect - change all `||` to `&&`.

Comment: Think carefully of what the condition would evaluate to if `action` is, say, `2`.

Answer (score 3):

change

```
while ((action != 1) || (action != 2) || (action != 3) || (action != 4)); // (1)
```

to

```
while ((action != 1) && (action != 2) && (action != 3) && (action != 4)); // (2)
```

**Analysis:**

if `action == 1`

(1) will evaluate to

```
while(false || true || true || true)
```

=>

```
while (true)
```

(2) will evaluate to

```
while(false && true && true && true)
```

=>

```
while (false)
```

Comment: Also check for success on `cin >> action` otherwise it'll continually use the last successfully-entered value. Easy way to do this would be `while( cin && (action != 1) && `...

Answer (score 1):

This is quite clumsy since you're essentially having to test the conditions twice. (Your specific problem is in the boolean test being incorrect: you need `&&` rather than `||`).

Consider using a function instead with validation built in:

```
int getAction(void)
{
    for (;;)/*infinite loop idiom*/{
        int action; /*scope as local as possible*/
        cin >> action;
        if (action >=1 || action <= 4){
            return action; /*this is ok, so return*/
        }
        cout << "I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you want to do. Please tell me again using the corresponding number. (1/2/3/4)\n\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead Of "or" condition try "and" condition
it will resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

It is only pausing in the default because you are asking for input and assigning action.

You should really be initialising action before the loop. Once action has been assigned 1, 2, 3, 4 it will loop forever as that is what the code says to do. You never change its value again, so the while statement just keeps spinning.

In your case statements you need to do whatever action is required and if you want to exit the loop add a flag for exit on the while. Break just marks the end of the case statement to stop it running into the next one.